# Why doesn't frame option allowframebreaks work when using the label option?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

When compiling with the parameter `label` as in the MWE, `allowframebreaks` doesn't work. Why not?

Is there any difference between setting a frame title as a `frame` argument and by using `\frametitle`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,label=frame1]{Title}
%\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Sub-title}
\blindtext
Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........
Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........
Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ 
Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ Text........ 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From manual: *Labels can be used as target of hyperjumps. A convenient way of labelling a frame is to use the label=⟨name⟩
option of the frame environment. However, this will cause **the whole frame to be kept in memory till the
end of the compilation**, which may **pose a problem** *. Maybe move label after begin of frame solve your problem (not tested).

Comment: @Zarko it works with `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]\label{frame1}...contents...` but not sure if it's a better way.

Comment: In your case it seems that this is only way :-). Try to inform the package maintainer about your problem.

Comment: @JosephWright (not sure if that will notify) is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: That won't notify. Try pinging him in chat. But I don't think this is a bug. `\label{frame1}` is not equivalent to passing `label=frame1` as an argument to the `frame`. The former puts a label at this point. The latter labels the entire frame. But that doesn't make sense when using `allowframebreaks`. (Aside from the fact that this should pretty much never be used.) Because the `frame` is not one in that case.

Comment: @cfr just to avoid such error, what do you think about the idea of setting the label to the first frame (before the break), how about the seconde part of the question about title ?

Comment: The title part of the question I don't understand. Why do you think that's relevant? What am I looking at exactly?

Comment: Do note: one question per question ... ;). I assumed you think the second question has something to do with the problem asked about in the first.

Comment: @cfr no i believe the difference between `\framesubtitle{title}` and `\begin{frame}{Title}` is trivial that why i added here

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237340/label-in-frame-options-disable-allowframebreaks-in-beamer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be a difference between setting the title as an argument to `frame` and using `\frametitle` if the next thing TeX finds is a `{` because this will be interpreted either as the start of the frame's subtitle or as the start of the frame's content.

For example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}{\centering A sunny day\par}And a gloomy one.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}{\centering A sunny day\par}And a gloomy one.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

demonstrates the difference between using the argument to `frame`

[image: as argument]

and using the macro

[image: as macro]

---

In `beamerbaseframe.sty`, we find

```
\define@key{beamerframe}{label}{\def\beamer@againname{#1}%
  {\let\@elt\beamer@labelsavecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
}
```

`beamerbaseframesize.sty` shows that `allowframebreaks` sets the toggle `beamer@autobreak` to `true`. Back in `beamerbaseframe.sty` we find, for example,

```
\newenvironment{beamer@frameslide}{%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak\else% i.e. unless allowframebreaks is requested ...
    \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty% if label isn't set ...
      {\let\@elt\beamer@restorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
    \else% otherwise i.e. we have label=<some label> ...
      {\let\@elt\beamer@labelrestorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  ...
```

So the mechanism activated by passing the `label` option to the `frame` environment is only used at all if `allowframebreaks` is not set to `true`.

It is important to appreciate that the `label` option is not equivalent to saying `\label{}` at any point. The `label` option is designed for something significantly more complex. Its main purpose is to support `\againframe`. For this purpose it names each slide of the current frame. Each slide also gets a label. If `label=mylabel`, then the slides get labels `mylabel<1>`, `mylabel<2>` etc. As a convenience, an additional label is set on the first slide `mylabel`. So, assuming the frame has *n* slides, setting this option is equivalent to saying

```
\label{mylabel}\label{mylabel<1>}% on the first slide
\label{mylabel<2>}% on the second slide
...
\label{mylabel<n>}% on the nth slide
```

This mechanism serves no purpose if `allowframebreaks` is set because overlays are disabled in this case.

Of course, you could code the option so that, if `allowframebreaks` is `true`, then `label` issues `\label{}` on the first frame. However, this would be potentially confusing since it would mean that the `label` option activated very different mechanisms depending on whether frames were allowed to be broken or not.

Comment: indeed if we have a group `{...}` just after `\begin{frame}` and we dont want it to be the title we are forced to use `\frametitle{}` instead

Comment: The other scenario if we dont want it to be the subtitle, we can enforce empty subtitle(or set one) `\begin{frame}{title here}{}{\centering test}` or using `\framesubtitle{}`...again we have choice

Comment: Yes, of course. You asked if there was a difference. My example is a case in which there is a significant difference.

Comment: @SAM Also, see edit above re. labelling. The real point here is that you are not meant to use `allowframebreaks` for regular frames at all. It is provided only for those very rare cases where it would be difficult or impossible to break the frames manually e.g. in the middle of displayed maths or the bibliography or something. The vast majority of presentations should not use `allowframebreaks` at all.